# Needed advice to automate REST services test

Tags: python, rest, testing, automated-tests

I am kind of new to REST and testing dept. I needed to write automation scripts to test our REST services. We are planning to run these scripts from a Jenkins CI job regularly. I prefer writing these in python as we already have UI functionality testing scripts in python generated by selenium IDE, but I am open to any good solution. I checked httplib, simplejson and Xunit, but looking for better solutions available out there.

And also, I would prefer to write a template and generate actual script for each REST API by reading API info from XML or something.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? That the response is what you would expect?

Comment: Yes, need to verify response data. Thinking of testing all the CRUD rest api actions. For example using REST APIs, Create five employees, read employees back, update some and finally delete all...I am thinking in this line of actions.

Comment: Via Groovy below is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972221/api-automation-groovy-soapui-all-together-for-most/38974183#38974183

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I usually use [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) to test my restful APIs.  The following example is in Ruby, but could easily be translated to python using either [the rubypy gem](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin-python) or [lettuce](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce).

Start with a set of RESTful base steps:

```
When /^I send a GET request for "([^\"]*)"$/ do |path|
  get path
end

When /^I send a POST request to "([^\"]*)" with the following:$/ do |path, body|
  post path, body
end

When /^I send a PUT request to "([^\"]*)" with the following:$/ do |path, body|
  put path, body
end

When /^I send a DELETE request to "([^\"]*)"$/ do |path|
  delete path
end

Then /^the response should be "([^\"]*)"$/ do |status|
  last_response.status.should == status.to_i
end

Then /^the response JSON should be:$/ do |body|
  JSON.parse(last_response.body).should == JSON.parse(body)
end
```

And now we can write features that test the API by actually issuing the requests.

```
Feature: The users endpoints

  Scenario: Creating a user
    When I send a POST request to "/users" with the following:
      """
      { "name": "Swift", "status": "awesome" }
      """
    Then the response should be "200"

  Scenario: Listing users
    Given I send a POST request to "/users" with the following:
      """
      { "name": "Swift", "status": "awesome" }
      """
    When I send a GET request for "/users"
    Then the response should be "200"
    And the response JSON should be:
      """
      [{ "name": "Swift", "status": "awesome" }]
      """

   ... etc ...
```

These are easy to run on a CI system of your choice.  See these links for references:

- [Testing REST APIs With Cucumber and Rack](https://anthonyeden.com/2013/07/10/testing-rest-apis-with-cucumber-and-rack.html)
- [The pain of JSON API testing](https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/the-pain-of-json-api-testing/)
- [Running your Cukes in Jenkins](https://web.archive.org/web/20190104175310/http://cheezyworld.com/2011/08/09/running-your-cukes-in-jenkins/)

Comment: Thanks Swift. I'll follow your example.

Answer (score 1):

```
import openpyxl
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

urlHead='https://IP_ADDRESS_HOST:PORT_NUMBER/'

rowStartAt=2
apiColumn=2
#payloadColumn=3
responseBodyColumn=12
statusCodeColumn=13

headerTypes = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
               'Accept':'application/json',
                'Authorization': '23324'
               }

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Excel_WORKBOOK.xlsx')

# PROCESS EACH SHEET
for sheetName in (wb.get_sheet_names()):
    print ('Sheet Name = ' + sheetName)

    flagVar = input('Enter N To avoid APIs Sheets')
    if (flagVar=='N'):
        print ('Sheet got skipped')
        continue


    #get a sheet
    sheetObj = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)

    #for each sheet iterate the API's
    for i in range(2, sheetObj.max_row+1):
        #below is API with method type
        apiFromSheet = (sheetObj.cell(row=i, column=apiColumn).value)
        if apiFromSheet is None:
            continue

        #print (i, apiFromSheet)
        #Let's split the api
        apiType = apiFromSheet.split()[0]
        method = apiFromSheet.split()[1]

        if (apiType!='GET'):
            continue

        #lets process GET API's
        absPath = urlHead + method
        print ("REQUESTED TYPE AND PATH = ", apiType, absPath)
        print('\n')


        res = requests.get(absPath, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pwd),           verify=False, headers=headerTypes)

        #LET's write res body into relevant cell
        sheetObj.cell(row=i, column=responseBodyColumn).value = (res.text)
        sheetObj.cell(row=i, column=statusCodeColumn).value =  (res.status_code)
        wb.save('Excel_WORKBOOK.xlsx')



          `#exit(0)`
```

Answer (score 0):

To automate REST API tests, there is a plugin for Pytest called Tavern, designed specifically for API testing.

You just need to install with pip `pip install tavern`

Then, you can create your test cases in a YAML file.

```
---
- name: Test GET endpoint
  request:
    url: /api/endpoint
    method: GET
  response:
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    body:
      message: Hello, world!
```

In this test case, you send a GET request to an endpoint and expect a response with a status code of 200, a JSON content type header, and a specific message in the response body.

There are many more configurations and complex scenarios possible, for that, check [tavern docs](https://tavern.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

To run the tests, execute `pytest <your_test_file>` in the command line. Tavern will handle the API requests and validate the responses based on the assertions.

To integrate Tavern with Jenkins CI, you just need to include a test execution step in your Jenkins job configuration and run the YAML file with pytest like mentioned above.