# API automation groovy soapui all together for most

Tags: json, excel, groovy, soapui

What automation to do when have to test REST APIs, how to do, and how to get final conformance report, great to be in excel workbook having all API's test report detail.

Input file can be an excel workbook or XML file, let's say excel having APIs detail.

Main problem I am facing in comparing input expected and response payload, please consider it as JSON and as a result decision should be taken stating test PASS/FAIL.

In answer section going to upload developed scripts to do most of the automation except conformance over JSON, which I am looking here.

Comment: Question is little unclear and broad. Would you please precise your question?

Comment: Sure, it's about automated testing of REST APIs from end to end. Eg. input is a list of api's are in excel file and output should be stating response payload having schema as expected, so decision can be taken it's pass/fail.

Comment: And in answer part, I have added details regarding things which are already done and what is remaining to do.

Answer (score 0):

- `"problem I am facing in comparing input expected and response payload"` - Have you tried using [zerocode rest test](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/wiki) library ?
  You can **copy paste** the JSON into the request response of the **test case** and then the framework takes care of **comparing** and **asserting**.. 
  And/Or You can place/organize them in the `src/test/resources` and point them from your test cases(JUnit or Suite). Frameworks then takes care of end point invocation using `apache HttpClient`, also optionally you can [override the HttpClient](https://github.com/authorjapps/helpme/blob/master/zerocode-rest-help/src/test/java/org/jsmart/zerocode/testhelp/zcmore/ZeroCodeUnitRunnerWithCustomHttpClient.java) in your way(if you need).
- `"how to get final conformance report, great to be in excel workbook having all API's test report detail"` - It generates report in the tabular excel format with result **PASS/FAIL** in the **last column**([See here sample report](https://github.com/authorjapps/helpme/blob/master/zerocode-rest-help/src/test/resources/zz_reports/zerocode_full_report_2016-07-30T11-44-14.512.csv)) in to the target folder for every run with timestamped. Also you get a [Spike Interactive Report](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/authorjapps/helpme/blob/master/zerocode-rest-help/src/test/resources/zz_reports/zerocode_results_chart_2016-07-30T09-55-53.056.html) with statistics of which API took how much time(in mili second). **Hover the mouse** on the individual spike to list the details.
- See the **Test Report** and **Test Log** section [here](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/wiki) for more details.
- Beauty is no extra code is needed other than your request/response JSON

Hope this helps :-)